# How do you display # of information between 2 number from a Array?

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8

How to display the numbers of students in each of the Levels (R, 1, 2, 3, 4)?

This program takes numbers a user enters: R is 50 and lower, Level 1 is  40-60, Level 2 is 60-70, Level 3 is 70-80 and Level 4 is  80+

I am using an array:

```
ArrayList<Integer> strArray = new ArrayList<>();
```

to display the information that a person enters. I am just having some troubles. Can someone help me? I am using NetBeans.

Example Input: 12,32,56,76,89,87,78

I want to be able to make it so it says R:2, Lvl 1:1, Lvl2:0 ,Lvl3:2, Lvl 4:2

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code which will help you,

```
   public void showResult()
   {
       int LevelR = 0, Level1 = 0, Level2 = 0, Level3 = 0, Level4 = 0;
       ArrayList<Integer> strArray = new ArrayList<>();

       strArray.add(12);
       strArray.add(32);
       strArray.add(56);
       strArray.add(76);
       strArray.add(89);
       strArray.add(87);
       strArray.add(78);

       for(int i : strArray)
       {

           if(i < 50)
           {
               LevelR++;
           }
           else if(i >= 50 && i < 60)
           {
               Level1++;
           }
           else if(i >= 60 && i < 70)
           {
               Level2++;
           }
           else if(i >= 70 && i < 80)
           {
               Level3++;
           }
           else if(i >= 80)
           {
               Level4++;
           }
       }

       System.out.println("R:" + LevelR + ", Lvl 1:" + Level1 + ", Lvl2:" + Level2 + " ,Lvl3:" + Level3 + ", Lvl 4:" + Level4);
   }
```

***I have added values statically inside function you can pass it in function and use it as per your requirement.***

Comment: thx lol i finished it before you could post this thx anyway but that program is still bugged you dont get values like 80 in catagores

Answer (score 0):

Here I have used if statement and save the result in a String . then store the string into the array list :

```
 ArrayList<Integer> strArray = new ArrayList<>(); 
int txtLevel =Integer.parseInt(userTxt.getText());
            String result ="";
            if(txtLevel >=40 && txtLevel <60){
                result = "Level 1";
            }
            else if(txtLevel >=60 && txtLevel <70){
                result = "Level 2";

            }else if(txtLevel >=70 && txtLevel <=80){
                result = "Level 3";
            }else {
                result = "Level 4";
            }
strArray.add(result);
```

Comment: I hope I got your question . However let me know if you need any help on that .

Comment: i got it to work i can help you a bit tho you have to write txtlevel==80 or it does not count any number like 70,80,60

Comment: i can use help on how to sort arrays strings

Answer (score 0):

With your question, I am assuming you are a beginner to Java still learning the basic concepts of programming.

You will have to follow the following steps:

1. You can define the ranges beforehand. The solution above will work too. Else you can use the `ValueRange` functionality of Java.
2. Scan the input string. You can use `Scanner` for the same.
3. After scanning the Input string, you have to separate the numbers by removing the commas.
4. You will have to map input numbers to their appropriate Range and get the number of input value in each Range.
5. Now you will have to produce the expected output

The solution below implements Steps(2-5) using Java8. It'll be useful for you to learn at this implementation too.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Define Range and their message in the output
    Map<ValueRange, String> rangeToMessage = new LinkedHashMap<ValueRange, String>() {
        {
            put(ValueRange.of(0, 40), "R");
            put(ValueRange.of(40, 60), "Lvl 1");
            put(ValueRange.of(60, 70), "Lvl 2");
            put(ValueRange.of(70, 80), "Lvl 3");
            put(ValueRange.of(80, Integer.MAX_VALUE), "Lvl 4");
        }
    };
    //Process Input String
    String input = "12,32,56,76,89,87,78";
    input.split(",");
    List<String> strArray = Arrays.asList(input.split(","));
    Function<Integer, Optional<ValueRange>> getRange = value -> rangeToMessage.keySet().stream()
            .filter(t -> t.isValidIntValue(value)).findFirst();
    //Map input numbers to their appropriate Range and get the number of input value in each Range
    Map<ValueRange, Long> rangeNcount = strArray.stream().map(Integer::parseInt).map(getRange)
            .filter(opt -> opt.isPresent()).map(opt -> opt.get())
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
    //Produce expected output message
    Function<ValueRange,Long> getCount = range-> (rangeNcount.get(range)==null)?Long.valueOf(0):rangeNcount.get(range);
    String outputMessage = rangeToMessage.keySet().stream().map(range->rangeToMessage.get(range)+":"+getCount.apply(range)).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
    System.out.println(outputMessage);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

how I solved it but it is messy

```
 int size=strArray.size();
 int sum=0;
 int a=0;
 int b=0;
 int c=0;
 int d=0;
 int e=0;

 int aver=sum/size;

for(int counter=0;counter<strArray.size();counter++){
    sum+=strArray.get(counter);

        if (strArray.get(counter)<50){
        a++;
        }
        if (strArray.get(counter)<60 && strArray.get(counter)>=50 && strArray.get(counter)==50)
        {
        b++;

        }if (strArray.get(counter)<70 && strArray.get(counter)>=60 && strArray.get(counter)==60){
        c++;
        }if (strArray.get(counter)<80 && strArray.get(counter)>=70 && strArray.get(counter)==70){
        d++;
        }if (strArray.get(counter)>=80 && strArray.get(counter)==80){
        e++;          
  }
}

            this.done.append("the average is: "+aver+
                    "Maximim value:"+Collections.max(strArray)+
            "Minimum value"+Collections.min(strArray)+
            "\nNumber of level 4: " + e+"\nNumber of level 3: "
            +d+"\nNumber of level 2: "+c+"\nNumber of level 1: "+b
            +"\nNumber of level R: "+a);
```

my Array int is just called str array if anyone got confused.

if I am on this site and anyone needs help on this assignment just ask me, I feel ur pain I had to learn everything from google and youtube.